# Suppose that $f(z) = g(z)/h(z)$ is analytic on the annulus $\{1 < |z| < 2\}.$ Show that $f$ can be written as $f = G(z)/H(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $g, h$ are continuous, nowhere vanishing functions on $\{|z| < 2\},$ $\{{|z| > 1} ∪ ∞\}$ respectively. Suppose that $f(z) = g(z)/h(z)$ is analytic on the annulus $\{1 < |z| < 2\}.$ Show that $f$ can be written as $f = G(z)/H(z)$ where $G, H$ are nowhere vanishing analytic functions on $\{|z| < 2\}, \{|z| > 1\}∪∞$ respectively.

I am to sure what theorem to invoke here.  Does anyone have a suggestion?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since the domains of $g$ and $h$ are simply connected, they have continuous logarithms. Thus $f$ has a continuous logarithm $L = \log g - \log h$ on the annulus $1 < \lvert z\rvert < 2$. Since $f$ is holomorphic, the continuous logarithm $L$ of $f$ is also holomorphic. Hence $L$ has a Laurent decomposition. Conclude.